# Setting text in TextView from another method

Tags: android, methods, textview, settext

There are many similar questions to this one, but they all ask about setting the text in a TextView from another CLASS.  I want to know if there is a short and simple way to change the text from another METHOD within the same class.

So everything is in one class, but the TextView is setup in method 1, and i want to set the text for this text view in method 2.

Before posting duplicate question replies and down-voting me, please read the question.  I want to change the text from WITHIN the same class, just on different methods.

More info...

```
//Method 1 has:
final TextView tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

//Method 2 has...
tvTitle.setText("TITLE");
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. You have just to do something like `yourTextView.setText("New text");` in your `method 2`

Comment: yourTextView cannot be resolved when i try to do that. it makes me do everything in the same method

Comment: Are you declared `yourTextView` as an attribute of your class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the object before using it, you have two solutions to your problem :

First solution :

```
public class MyClass
{
    private TextView tvTitle;

    MyClass()
    {
           tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    }
}
```

Or second method :

In the two method write this line :

`TextView tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);`

But the first is a better solution